# How to create two classes having the same entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

Let's assume that I have a `table` `person` and that I have an entity class for it, with lots of fields, some `@Exposed`, some `@Transient`, some `@Temporal` columns. The problem is that loading n `Person` items takes a long while because for each record there are some fields which reduce performance.

As an idea for optimization I have created a `PersonSimplified` class, defining all the members of `Person`, except the "slow" fields and methods. Everything worked impeccably, but this solution is not very elegant, unfortunately, because things, like `name` are redefined and code duplication is a recipe for disaster. My idea is to ensure that `Person extends PersonSimplified`, but cannot figure out how to do that. I have three important classes, I will give their skeleton here:

BaseEntity.java

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners({BaseEntityListener.class})
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Cloneable {
    //Some fields and methods
}
```

PersonSimplified.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity(name="PersonSimplified")
@Table(name="person")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class PersonSimplified extends BaseEntity implements Auditable, Serializable {
    //Lots of stuff
}
```

Person.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity(name="Person")
@Table(name="person")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person extends PersonSimplified implements Auditable, Serializable {
    //Some slow stuff
}
```

The error I get is:

Foreign key circularity dependency involving the following tables: person, person

However, I do not intend to have any foreign keys. I would only like to reorganize the code to ensure that when I need a simplified person, it's available, when I need it along with slow fields, then I can achieve that as well and I do not have to duplicate my code. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is related to the @Inheritance, please try this:

PersonSimplified.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity(name="PersonSimplified")
@Table(name="person")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class PersonSimplified extends BaseEntity implements Auditable, Serializable {
    //Lots of stuff
}
```

Person.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity(name="Person")
@Table(name="person")
public class Person extends PersonSimplified implements Auditable, Serializable {
    //Some slow stuff
}
```

You must know that under the hood, Hibernate is generating a discriminator column and the discriminator value for Person.

EDIT

The actual solution was to create an intermediate `class`, which `extends` `BaseEntity` and from which the other two classes are extended:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners({BaseEntityListener.class})
public abstract class BasePerson extends BaseEntity {
    //Everything which was part of PersonSimplified
}
```

and then I have made sure to extend this `class`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity(name="PersonSimplified")
@Table(name="person")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class PersonSimplified extends BasePerson implements Auditable, Serializable {

    public PersonSimplified() {
    }

}
```

and

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity(name="Person")
@Table(name="person")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person extends BasePerson implements Auditable, Serializable {
    //Slow stuff
}
```

and the result was great, the optimization was a superb success.

Comment: Hi, Villat, I have tried your suggestion and got this error: Unknown column 'this_.DTYPE' in 'field list', Sorry for the slow reply, solved the issue yesterday.

Comment: I have inherited a new class from BaseEntity called BasePerson with settings like 
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners({BaseEntityListener.class})

and moved everything from PersonSimplified into BasePerson. Finally, I've made sure that both PersonSimplified and Person extends BasePerson.

Comment: Since none of the sources I have found were helpful for my case, I have switched to plan B and created a new class between BaseEntity and the actual entity classes, so this new class contains everything common for any Person, basically everything PersonSimplified contained.

Comment: @LajosArpad that's great! I thought about that approach, but it wasn't what you were looking for. Please, share your answer in this post :)

Comment: I have edited your answer accordingly, to make sure future readers will know how to solve it.